# "wieder je", Nathan der Weise (I.1, 30)

Tags: translation, phrase, literature

Ich brauche Hilfe, um einen Auszug (I.1, 30) aus [Nathan der Weise](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nathan_der_Weise) zu verstehen.

**Hier ist [der Auszug](http://www.zeno.org/Literatur/M/Lessing,+Gotthold+Ephraim/Dramen/Nathan+der+Weise/1.+Akt/1.+Auftritt) (I.1, 30-31):**

(Nathan glaubte fälschlicherweise, dass seine Tochter tot sei. Er hat gerade erfahren, dass sie noch lebt und ruft: )

> NATHAN.
>   Wenn ich mich wieder je entwöhnen müßte,
>   Dies Kind mein Kind zu nennen!

Was bedeutet "wieder je" ? Ich sehe zwei Möglichkeiten :

- entweder "je wieder" und "wieder je" haben dieselbe Bedeutung. Für mich "je wieder" bedeutet "~ nie...noch einmal, ~nie...mehr" wie in "Keiner wurde je wieder gesehen." (~ Aucun n'en est jamais revenu, ~ No one has ever been seen again).

Aber in diesem Fall verstehe ich Lessings Text nicht. An dieser Stelle im Stück hatte Nathan noch nie die Gelegenheit gehabt, Recha "sein Kind" nicht zu nennen. In diesem Fall, warum "wieder" ?

- entweder dient "wieder" nur dazu, "je" zu verstärken.

**Ihre Hilfe ist willkommen !**

Comment: Please don’t use code formatting if not necessary: it doesn’t support automatic line breaks, which means on mobile devices all text after the first few words is not readable...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es handelt sich um einen Satz im Konjunktiv II, also im Reich der Nicht-Fakten.

Nathan überlegt laut, was denn wäre, **müsste** er zukünftig nochmals (wieder je == je wieder) so etwas erleben.

*Wieder je* ist eine nicht übliche Reihenfolge und bedeutet dasselbe wie *je wieder*. Hier ist das wohl dem Rhythmus geschuldet.

Comment: "Hier ist das wohl dem Rhythmus geschuldet." Das Stück ist in Blankversen geschrieben (reimlose fünfhebige Jamben mit männl. oder weibl. Kadenz). Also ja.